# Problem with custom label in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have UITableViewController. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I added custom setup for label:

```
UILabel *lblMainLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 9, 150, 25)];
    lblMainLabel.text = c.Name;
    lblMainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    lblMainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblMainLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblMainLabel];
    [lblMainLabel release];
```

But when I scroll UP or DOWN in table it always add this label on top of previous what I miss?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should create the UILabel exactly one time, when you create the cell.

Your code should look like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = ...
   UILabel *lblMainLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 9, 150, 25)];
   lblMainLabel.tag = 42;
   lblMainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
   lblMainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   lblMainLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:lblMainLabel];
   [lblMainLabel release];
}
UILabel *lblMainLabel = [cell viewWithTag:42];
lblMainLabel.text = c.Name;
```

Comment: Why should the tag be of the number 42? Or doesn't it really matter?

Comment: The tag is of course an arbitrary number. But you have to use the same number when you assign the tag and when you retrieve the view with the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes fluchtpunkt, you are right. 
cellForRowAtIndexPath gets fired every times the tableview scrolls, it will reloads the data.

```
if (cell == nil)
{

}
```

will get fired once the cell is allocating. else memory also gets increased.

Comment: If you agree with an answer please upvote it and, perhaps, add a comment. This isn't really an "answer."