# tableview using array not working - xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm designing an app for my school and I am trying to make a simple directory using a tableview within a view controller. I began by trying to make objects, but then switched to a more simple array, still without any luck. I do not know if it is a problem with the code or with the storyboard. Here is the code for the viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class DirectoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var backButton2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var directoryTableView: UITableView!

    // @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    // var directoryObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    var names = ["Teacher 1", "Teacher 2", "Teacher 3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*  
        self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 1")
        self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 2")
        self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 3")

        self.directoryTableView.reloadData()
        */
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    // Mark - tableview

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let directoryCell = self.directoryTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("directoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DirectoryTableViewCell

        // directoryCell.directoryLabel.text = self.directoryObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

        directoryCell.directoryLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return directoryCell
    }


    @IBAction func backButton2Tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the DirectoryTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class DirectoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var directoryLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
/*
    func directoryTableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Set the delegates.

Comment: would that be in the code or in the storyboard?

Comment: Either, it's up to you. I'll add instructions as an answer

Comment: `self.directoryTableView.delegate = self` and `self.directoryTableView.datasource = self` in` viewDidLoad`

Comment: Or in the storyboard, you can drag from the `tableView` to your `DirectoryViewController` (either the yellow circle with the white square at the top of the view, or in the document outline) and select both `dataSource` and `delegate`. Or even once you have selected the `tableView` drag from the `dataSource` and `delegate` options under the outlets heading in the connections inspector on the right of the page (utilities panel) to the view controller.

Comment: It has been answered already here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25545185/3947151

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegates. The easiest way is in the code.

In `viewDidLoad` add:

```
directoryTableView.delegate = self
directoryTableView.dataSource = self
```

This will allow those `tableView` functions to get called.

I'd also recommend changing:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 3
}
```

to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return names.count
}
```

Comment: now it is showing the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION to the line            directoryCell.directoryLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]

Comment: Well I don't know anything about you `DirectoryTableViewCell`, but it should be working otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, when defining your cell, try changing `self.directoryTableView` to `tableView` in the first line.

Comment: Also have you created a prototype cell with the identifier specified?

Comment: Yes in storyboard I created a prototype cell. It has a label that is linked to the DirectoryTableViewCell and the cell identifier is directoryCell.

Comment: Try commenting out that line and see if it runs

Comment: @WMios I commented out that line and now it runs and there are three cells, but they all just say "Label" which is what the prototype cell says.

Comment: So then it seems that you have an issue with how the label is setup. Do you need the custom class? Why not just set the titleLabel which is built into the UITableViewCell class?

Comment: I would say your initial question has been answered. I would look into other people who have had this next issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967554/problem-with-custom-label-in-uitableviewcell)